# How do I connect 1/4" plastic tube to 3/8" sink connector outlet

Tags: plumbing, adapter

I have a 3/8 inch O.D. male threaded sink connector supply line (which hooks up to a standard 3/8 faucet hose) which I need to connect to 1/4 inch plastic tubing. What adapters do I need?

I purchased the 3/8 threaded to 1/4 compression adapter at True Value, but the threaded diameter was too large. What fitting is required for this?

Please be specific and reference actual products, otherwise the answer will not be of value.

Comment: Your "3/8 inch O.D. male threaded sink connector" is that your supply valve?

Comment: Can you add a sketch of exactly what you need to connect, including what everything connects to?  Crayons on a napkin will be fine.

Comment: The connection only has two parts the 3/8 supply and the 1/4 tubing.

Comment: You can find pre-made adapters to go from almost anything to almost anything.  Have you browsed the hardware store aisle or looked online?

Comment: Yes I browsed the plumbing in two true values. The ice maker connector kits seemed to have what I needed along with other stuff. I could not find a separate adapter even though I would assume this is a common problem. Online the labels are often not specific enough. The true value adapter was labeled with 3/8 but was not O.D, probably FIP.

Comment: The point is I want to use the existing threads from the soldered-on 1/2" nom inlet x 3/8" od outlet to connect to the 1/4" tubing in as few adapter steps as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the fitting:

LASCO 17-6755 3/8-Inch Female Compression by 1/4-Inch Male Compression Brass Adapter